# Monotonicity and continuity

Tags: calculus

A function $f(x)$ is monotonic on the interval $(a, b)$ and continuous on $[a, b]$. Prove that the function is monotonic on $[a, b]$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is non-decreasing on $(a,b)$. Let $a<x \leq b$. Then $f(a+\frac  1 n) \leq f(x)$ whenever $a+\frac 1 n <x$ (which is true whenever $n >\frac 1 {x-a}$. Letting $n \to\infty$ we get $f(a) \leq f(x)$. Similarly $a \leq x <b$ implies $f(x) \leq f(b)$.Hence $f$ is non-decreasing on $[a,b]$.